# Custom DataContractResolver ResolveName DataContractResolver parameter should not be null

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

I am using a custom DataContractResolver

```
 public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
        {
            Type knownType = knownTypeResolver.ResolveName(typeName, typeNamespace, declaredType, null);

            if (knownType != null)
            {
                return knownType;
            }...
```

The same case is with the TryResolve method (which I don't require)

```
public override bool TryResolveType(Type type, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver, out XmlDictionaryString typeName, out XmlDictionaryString typeNamespace)
        {
           return knownTypeResolver.TryResolveType(type, declaredType, null, out typeName, out typeNamespace);
```

Resharper tells me, that the last parameter should not be null, as it is marked with the `[NotNull]` attribute.

[image]

The ResolveName method is also overwritten by the `System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeDataContractResolver` class.

This is the implementation:

```
public override Type ResolveName(string typeName, string typeNamespace, Type declaredType, DataContractResolver knownTypeResolver)
    {
      if (typeName == null || typeNamespace == null)
        return (Type) null;
      else
        return this.context.ResolveNameFromKnownTypes(new XmlQualifiedName(typeName, typeNamespace));
    }
```

The parameter `knownTypeResolver` is not even used!

All the examples I see are using it the way I am. 
What is the correct implementation?

Comment: ReSharper could be wrong?

Comment: @MichaelDamatov: Where does the [NotNull] in the image above come from?

Comment: The .NET framework assemblies are not annotated by Microsoft. ReSharper is shipped with _external_ annotations (ReSharper _believes_ to be fully correct).